# Java Runtime Environment was not found at bin\javaw.exe

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, odac

When I tried to install ODAC component in Windows Server 2008 machine, it thrown below error.

"Java Runtime Environment was not found at `bin\javaw.exe`. Hence the Oracle Universal Installer cannot be run. Please visit http://www.javasoft.com and install JRE version 1.4 or higher and try again"

I found `javaw.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin`

I searched in google and added the value in PATH of Environment Variable as below

`C:\program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;`  //not worked

`C:\progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;`       //not worked

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` environment variables set pointing to the installed locations?

Comment: Can  you check 1) java -version 2) echo %JAVA_HOME% at command prompt??

Comment: I haven't given any environment variables with JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME

Comment: @Invisible Arrow mean, will you set PATH environment variable correctly to your java installed locations??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I was copying ODAC setup file to server, it didn't copied completely. The setup file is only 30 MB in server where as the original one is 290MB. Server is not copying big size files properly. So, I downloaded the component from internet and executed the exe file. Its working fine now.
Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `JAVA_HOME` is not mandatory, you can add `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin` in your `PATH`. Make sure to add a `;` before the last entry and then add your entry.

After doing that open command prompt and run command `java -version` and see if you `PATH` is correctly configured indeed. you will see valid version info if it is. If is says `is not recognized as an internal or external command` , then check your `PATH` variable again and see if its set properly.

Comment: I gave ; properly and run the command java -version. it gave valid version information.

Comment: It means that your jre is properly configured in path, It might need variable `JRE_LOCATION`, add a variable `JRE_LOCATION` and set it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25`, create the variable in both user and system variables. Tell me if this works

Comment: Is it in System variables or user variables?

Comment: Add in both , I am not sure, although it should be in system, it wont harm adding in both :).

Comment: Added in both System and User. Still couldn't able to install

Comment: Set `JAVA_HOME` too , poitning to same location.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you get this error because of java installed on path "C:\Program Files\Java".
I faced similar issue and solved with these steps...

- Simply run setup file (in my case I was trying to install oracle ODI).
- New cmd window will open and will ask for JDK path (give your JDK path see example below).

[image]

- Installation should begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below possible solution:

```
set JRE_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

OR

set JRE_LOCATION=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

OR

set JRE_LOCATION= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre

OR

set JRE_LOCATION= C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25
```

**Addition:**
Is something preventing the JVM from running (like anti-virus s/w,
Windows (your version fell off: don't know version) prohibit
running, ...). You should check, do you have administrator rights on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Installer does not able to understand C :\Program Files\Java\ ..I mean space between "Program Files" and hence failing. 
Please install Java in some other directory like
C:\JAVA\jre1.8.0_25
and then set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME
It should solve the problem.